# System unable to detect renamed/new files

Tags: filesystems, kernel, gentoo, inotify

Some months ago I realized when I am writing a new post on my blog (with Hugo), the feature to reload the contents as files changes stopped working.

I waited in order to see if it was a problem with hugo, but the problem is with my Gentoo. For example, if I rename a file, the file manager does not see it immediately, I have to press `F5` to be able to see the renamed file. The same happens if I download a file with the folder in which the file is being downloaded opened in the file manager.

I though the problem may be I didn't have installed `inotify-tools`, but it is installed.

In my kernel configuration I have `inotify` enabled:

```
grepr inot .config
CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y
```

Any ideas in which package I accidentally could have removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!, accidentally

I am working with ensime, and in its logs I saw this exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: User limit of inotify watches reached
```

So I just needed to increase the number of files that can be watch in systemctl:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=32768
```

Now everything is working right